# expo build doesnt change ios version

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, expo-build, expo-dev-client

i have expo app with prebuild, im trying to upload to test flight build.

I create build like this:

> npx expo prebuild -p ios && eas build -p ios

when its done, i see on the expo dashboard the build as iOS app Store Build 999.0.0 (12)
in my appstore i have version 3.0.0 ready for sale, so version 999.0.0 is only for test flight users.

but when i submit my build to appstore connect i get this error:

> Error: Asset validation failed This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [40.2.0].

what already done/check:
info.plist has CFBundleShortVersionString with key of 999.0.0 and not 1.0
package.json version change to 999.0.0
i add buildNumber cause i have 11 already in 999.0.0
i add in xcode in target the version and build too.
try prebuild on every change above.

but i still get 1.0 in the submission.

this is my app.json

```
  "expo": {
     "name": "name",
     "slug": "name",
     "version": "999.0.0", <----
     "orientation": "portrait",
     "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
     "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
     "splash": {
         "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
         "resizeMode": "contain",
         "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
     },
     "assetBundlePatterns": [
          "**/*"
      ],
     "ios": {
        "supportsTablet": true,
        "bundleIdentifier": "xxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx",
        "buildNumber": "12" <----
      },
    "extra": {
  "supportsRTL": false,
  "oneSignalAppId": "xxxxxxx",
  "router": {
    "origin": false
  },
  "eas": {
    "build": {
      "experimental": {
        "ios": {
          "appExtensions": [
            {
              "targetName": "OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension",
              "bundleIdentifier": "xxxxxxx",
              "entitlements": {
                "com.apple.security.application-groups": [
                  "xxxxxxxx"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "projectId": "xxxx"
  }
}
 },
 "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-xxx-xx-xxx~xxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-xxx-xxx-xxxx~xxx"
 }
```

***UPDATE***
I tried to change the shortVersion in Xcode and buildNumber as well, and upload from xcode and it works.
so its something with the eas cli or build

Comment: Did you create a new version in app store connect ?

Comment: thanks for responding, I already have 11 builds in this version(999.0.0) on the test flight.
so to answer your question, yes.
but the problem is coming before that saying my build is 1.0 and not 999.0.0

Comment: We have the same issue, we see that the prebuild still has the correct version in the `Info.plist` but the final app file does not.